# Unable to connect to Google Cloud Compute Engine external IP

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have set up a couple of Linux engines as a free test and for some reason I am unable to connect from my browser with http and https (both enabled in firewall)?

Just made it running and are able to SSH and Ping the server, but when I try with the browser I get a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED message.

Followed this guide:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/setting-up-lamp

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Apache may not be running on your server. Can you telnet to apache from your server. e.g try: telnet localhost 80. You can also try to shutdown and then start your server.

Comment: I have tried to restart the server a couple of times

Comment: I am for some reason now able to get access with http but https is not working - anybody know why?

Answer (score 0):

Verify if port 80 is in listening state on your GCE instance using the command:

```
netstat -tuplen
```

If port 80 is not in listening state, then it is possible that Apache service is not running on your instance. You can start the apache service depending upon the operating system in use. Refer to this [link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/star-stop-restart-apache2-webserver/) for information on starting the Apache service. Once Apache service is started, verify that port 80 is in listening state using the above command and verify accessing the instance using port 80 (https) from the web browser.